# casting byte[] to user defined class in java

Tags: java, serialization

i want to cast byte[] which i got from socket a class which I write it (Message).
I tried

```
byte[] data=new btyte[100];
.
.
.
Message m=(Message)data;
```

but it did not work and give me error
what should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a serialized object:

try this:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
in.close();
```

In case you are serializing the Message in some other way, you will have to parse it yourself, using a parametrized constructor or a static method that returns a new instance of the type.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot cast arbitrary binary data (in Java).

What's that byte[] supposed to contain? If it's a serialized instance of the class, you'll have to wrap the socket's InputStream in an [ObjectInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html). If it's aother well-defined binary format, you'll have to parse it manually (Note: dumping C structs does not constitute a well-defined binary format and should be avoided).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off writing a function to do it.

```
Message parseDataFromSocket(byte[] bytes);
```

Comment: The implementation of this function whould be a better answer.

Comment: No, it wouldn’t because the OP has never specified in which format the data is stored—any answer would be quite wrong unless Seth can read minds or guesses correctly.

Comment: actually this is a good answer since you can hide how the "parse" works - if could be really parsing or it could be unpickling a serialized object... best thing is that the user of the method would not really care how it gets done, just that it gets done.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `ObjectInputStream` with a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

It looks like your trying to read a serialized class.

Edited to ByteArrayInputStream as mention above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Message constructor that takes a byte[] (and uses it to somehow initialise the object).  You can then do:

```
Message m = new Message(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the byte array was serialized normally, you can use a `ByteArrayInputStream`, pass that into an `ObjectInputStream` and cast the resulting `Object` into your `Message` class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the byte array was created... You could try:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
Message m = (Message) in.readObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java it is **not possible to perform such casts** (in C++, for example, one can define conversion constructors and the likes).

You've tagged the question with 'serialization'. Assuming you are **using the Java serialization API**, then as you were already directed, you should feed the `data` array through an `ObjectInputStream` in order for it to deserialize the array into an object. More information can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Furthermore, in case you've used some other sort of serialization (for example, using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize to XML) then you should deserialize (unmarshalling is another common name for this) the data using the same API that was used to serialize it in the first place.